# confusion between self.variable and variable in a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

why the following code is giving output as vijay,change,10 
i am new to python and i dont understand what is instance variable and what is local variable. And

```
class Emp:
    name = "satya"
    def __init__(self,n):
        name = "change"            
        self.name = n
        self.var  = 10
        Emp.name=name

e = Emp("vijay")
print(e.name)
print(Emp.name)
print(e.var)
```

Comment: *i am new to python* - it doesn't excuse your unwillingness to learn. this difference is covered in tons of articles/books/tutorials - just search and read it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 'self' explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is covered both in Python documentation and a variety of 3rd-party articles easily found by Google. Example: http://timothyawiseman.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/class-and-instance-variables-in-python-2-7/